# Mysterious hidden environment variable in Windows 10

Tags: windows, environment-variables, visual-studio-2010

In Windows 10, I am using an environment variable to specify the installation directory of various source code libraries. In Visual Studio, I specify the include directories using my environment variable.

[image]

The first three lines use the environment variable WXWIN. In the Evaluated value section of the dialog box, you can see that it has been correctly evaluated to "D:\Libraries\wxWidgets".

However when I come to the code, I see that Visual Studio is no longer correctly evaluating the environment variable.

[image]

**Some background**
I originally installed wxWidgets using the installer. This installed to D:\Libraries\wxWidgets-3.1.2

Then I deleted that directory, and use git to clone my fork of wxWidgets into D:\Libraries\wxWidgets.

I suppose that somehow the original install has left its mark. However, I can't find any record of it in the registry.

Comment: Did you reboot? Also, it may be the case that you are viewing the editor of the user varables, while WXWIN could have been installed systemwide.

Comment: The system PATH variable also has a maximum length.  Be sure you have not ran into that limit

Comment: @DanielF - I did reboot. But isn't it strange that Visual Studio's project property editor sees the correct WXWIN (see screen shot), while the editor and the compiler see something else.

Comment: @Ramhound - I don't think that can be it, because the project property editor can clearly see the correct environment variable.

Comment: Can you confirme the location of */wx/wx.h*?

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes. wx.h is definitely in D:\Libraries\wxWidgets\include\wx\wx.h